# Change HTML Dropdown navigation position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website I inherited that is all HTML code (no CMS). I am dusting off my old skills but for the life of me I can't figure out how to move a dropdown menu over in the navigation.

This is the website: https://genquestnutrition.com/

I moved around the navigation menu and now if you hover over "Formulas" the dropdown menu is too far to the left. If probably needs to move 25 px to the right. Here is the code for that section:

```
<div class="xr_ar xr_nb0">

 <a href="javascript:;" aria-haspopup="true" onclick="return(xr_nn());">

  <img class="xr_rn_ xr_rnsp_ xr_ap" src="index_htm_files/8904.png" alt="Formulas" title="" style="left:390px;top:0px;width:60px;height:25px;"/>

  <img class="xr_rn_ xr_rnsp_ xr_ap xr_ro xr_ro0 xr_tt3" src="index_htm_files/8922.png" alt="Formulas" title="" onmousemove="xr_mo(this,220)" style="left:390px;top:0px;width:60px;height:25px;"/>

 </a>

  <div class="xr_nb2 xr_nb5 xr_smp310_-370" style="left:310px; top:25px; min-width:60px;">

  <ul class="xr_nb4">

   <li><a href="ree.htm">REE</a>

   </li> <li><a href="tee.htm">TEE</a>

   </li>

<li>
       
    <a href="https://www.easycalculation.com/health/mifflin-st-jeor-calculator.php" target="_blank">RMR Calc</a>

   </li>


  </ul>

  </div>

 </div>
```

Have have tried changing

```
<div class="xr_nb2 xr_nb5 xr_smp310_-370" style="left:310px; top:25px; min-width:60px;">
```

to

```
<div class="xr_nb2 xr_nb5 xr_smp310_-370" style="left:335px; top:25px; min-width:60px;">
```

thinking that the left absolute positioning would do it but it doesn't change when it is uploaded to the server.

I am not sure if I am missing some JS code somewhere that is overriding that or even where to search for it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE:

I found this code in `roe.js` that seems to refer to the area of concern using `xr_nb5` and `xr_smp`:

```
function xr_rpmnu() {
    var ll = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV');
    for (var i = 0; i < ll.length; i++) {
        if (ll[i].className.indexOf("xr_nb5") != -1) {
            if (ll[i].className.indexOf("xr_smp") != -1) {
                var x = ll[i].className.substr(ll[i].className.indexOf("xr_smp") + 6).split("_");
                var wre = (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) - 16;
                var wbe = (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) - 16;
                var r = ll[i].getBoundingClientRect();
                if (!r.right) {
                    setTimeout("xr_rpmnu();", 500);
                    return;
                };
                if (ll[i].className.indexOf("xr_nb51") != -1) {
                    ll[i].style.right = "";
                    ll[i].style.left = x[0] + "px";
                    r = ll[i].getBoundingClientRect();
                    if (r.right > wre) {
                        ll[i].style.left = "";
                        ll[i].style.right = x[1] + "px";
                    };
                } else if (ll[i].className.indexOf("xr_nb53") != -1) {
                    ll[i].style.left = "";
                    ll[i].style.right = x[0] + "px";
                    r = ll[i].getBoundingClientRect();
                    if (r.left < 0) {
                        ll[i].style.right = "";
                        ll[i].style.left = x[1] + "px";
                    };
                } else {
                    if (r.right < wre) {
                        ll[i].style.right = "";
                        ll[i].style.left = x[0] + "px";
                    };
                    r = ll[i].getBoundingClientRect();
                    if (r.right > wre) {
                        ll[i].style.left = "";
                        ll[i].style.right = x[1] + "px";
                    };
                };
            };
        };
        var l = ll[i].getElementsByTagName('LI');
        for (var j = 0; j < l.length; j++) {
            if (l[j].className.indexOf("xr_nb1") != -1) {
                xr_nbr(l[j].firstElementChild, 0);
            };
        };
    };
};
var xr_fitwidthlock = 0;
var xr_prevscale = 1;
var xr_prevscale1 = 1;
var xr_prevscale2 = 1;
var xr_ftwcnt = 0;
```

I am not sure if this is the correct section but if anyone can help with this it would be great. In the meantime, I just made the submenu wider.

Comment: Looks like it is some kind of CMS, or definitely a template generated. Javascript will most likely handle positioning of those dropdowns.

Comment: If you change the positioning left:310 to left:350 using the developer console and then swith co another element and then back- the left will be back to 310. I think roe.js changes the positioning (xr_nb2 class). Check the developer documentation/faq.

Comment: I just added some of the roe.js code above.

Comment: I believe the template you are using is coming from [Xara](https://www.xara.com/uk/web-designer/templates/), maybe you can investigate some more here or search specific community, or tag it here.

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix: instead adding style to link change add margin-left to the ul> dropdown

```
<div class="xr_nb2 xr_nb5 xr_smp310_-370" style="left:310px; top:25px; 
 min-width:150px;">
   <ul class="xr_nb4" style=" margin-left: 36px; width: 100%; ">   
   <li><a href="ree.htm">REE</a> 
   </li> <li><a href="tee.htm">TEE</a>  
   </li>  
   <li>        
    <a href="https://www.easycalculation.com/health/mifflin-st-jeor- 
           calculator.php" target="_blank">RMR Calc</a>
   </li> 
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).